# Play Java Guide application nr. 2 testing

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to walk through this guide:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide2 , but it lacks some explanations which make me lost. More preciesly:
a)at the end of "Starting with the User class" paragraph, I should have got error. I didn't. I thought "whatever" and moved along, which, in retrospect might have been a mistake.
b) I progressed to the "first test" , but it did not write where am I supposed to put my test. So, I put it in ApplicationTest.java. It failed my tests however, saying ebean was not defined. So, after googling a bit I tried to add `ebean.default="models.*"` in application.conf. It worked, but now I have

```
[error] Test ApplicationTest.createAndRetrieveUser failed: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
java.sql.SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool 
that has already been shutdown.
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

my application test

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import models.User;
import org.junit.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.test.*;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.validation.ValidationError;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.RequiredValidator;
import play.i18n.Lang;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.F.*;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import play.libs.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;

public class ApplicationTest {

@Test
public void simpleCheck() {
    int a = 1 + 1;
    assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
}

@Test
public void renderTemplate() {
    Content html = views.html.index.render("Your new application is ready.");
    assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
    assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Your new application is ready.");
}
@Test
public void createAndRetrieveUser() {
    new User("bob@gmail.com", "Bob", "secret").save();
    User bob = User.find.where().eq("email", "bob@gmail.com").findUnique();
    assertNotNull(bob);
    assertEquals("Bob", bob.name);
}

}
```

User class

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

@Id
public String email;
public String name;
public String password;

public User(String email, String name, String password) {
  this.email = email;
  this.name = name;
  this.password = password;
}

public static Finder<String,User> find = new Finder<String,User>(
    String.class, User.class
); 
}
```

application.conf

```
#tried with 'db.*' uncommented as well as with commented
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
# end of 'db.*'
ebean.default="models.*"
# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

Comment: Might need to see the User class.

Comment: @Compass added User class

Comment: Show your `application.conf`

Comment: added my application.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test `createAndRetrieveUser()` according to the tutorial should be in `test/models/ModelsTest.java`. You put it in `ApplicationTest.java`.